# speedup or mute audio playback in a windows process via hooking calls

Tags: c, windows, audio, hook

I have an application which I do not have source code for that plays back audio but lacks the facility to speed up or temporarily mute audio playback.  I am trying to add these two functionalities by injecting a dll and hooking waveOutOpen, waveOutWrite (and either preventing playback or trying to waveOutSetPlaybackRate for mute and speedup respectively).  I have a couple of problems however.

Lets first talk about the "mute" button since that was my first order of business:
I will refer to the hooked versions of functions as MyWaveOut...

1)
I am able to hook the functions no problem and I see them being called in dbgView log statements.  My first attempt was to just intercept waveOutWrite function calls and if my "mute" button is pressed to just return MMSYSERR_NOERROR in MyWaveOutWrite function and not call the real waveOutWrite.  This correctly prevents the audio from playing however I encounter a problem when I turn off the "mute" .  The audio does not play again when I disable the mute, in fact the hooked function (nor the real one) is ever called again by the hooked process.

My first suspicion was that I was not calling the callback waveOutProc that is registered by the application when it calls WaveOutOpen.  I therefore also hooked the waveOutOpen and kept and switched the address of the waveOutProc to MyWaveOutProc and added logic to call the real waveOutProc before returning the same MMSYSERR_NOERROR in MyWaveOutWrite.  This had weird results causing the playback visual to skip forward very fast but then I had the same problem with the audio not returning (MyWaveOutWrite function never called again).

2)

As for the audio speedup portion I tried using waveOutSetPlaybackRate but this simply returned MSYSERR_NOTSUPPORTED so I arrived at a dead end with that.  Hooking GetTickCount and QueryPerformanceCounter had no affect on the audio playback at all, the visual playback indicator would skip forward ahead fast if the audio is disabled, but when the audio device is enabled the visual seems even to be bound to the rate of the audio playback.

Any help with with those experienced with either of these problems would be appreciated.  I do not usually work with windows audio so it is a bit of a learning experience for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion for a different approach.

This assumes the OS is from Vista Kernnel or higher.
In these operation systems there is a pr application volume control, it might be simpler to mute it here then with any hooks.